# close a socket from shell

Tags: linux, sockets

I am working on a feature that relies on socket communication. One test case I am considering is abrupt socket failures. for ex: I want to close the socket the client has established from the shell, when the client & server are in the middle of some exchange. Is this doable though a shell command ?

Comment: what kind of sockets? named sockets? network sockets?

Comment: What are the two server and client programs? Self written? The you could add some feature "close/re-open socket" triggered by a signal (SIGHUP or SIGUSR1) sent by an external process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to close it (per your title), or abruptly interrupt it in order to test error-handling code (per your explanation)?

You should be able to interrupt communications on a particular socket using netfilter and appropriate match engines (e.g. pid and port number), and you definitely can run `iptables` from the shell.

If you want to close the socket, you can just terminate the peer process.

Comment: I want to close the socket. If that is not possible I can look into the option of interrupting the communication. will check out netfilter/iptables options. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Santhosh: Presumably you want your testing to reflect likely real-world failure conditions?  Dropped packets are a likely failure condition, an unexpectedly-closed socket not so much.

Answer (score 0):

No, not on standard linux, there is no such facility.